# Right align text inside a TextBox

Tags: .net, winforms, textbox

I would expect there would be a property that I need to set to align the text inside a TextBox, but I can't find it. I remember using [style="text-align:right"] in ASP.net, but what do I use in WinForms?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can change the [TextAlign](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.textalign.aspx) propety using [HorizontalAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.horizontalalignment.aspx) enumerator. Try something  like:

```
textBox1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
```

Comment: You're right. I just noticed that it's actually a RadTextBoxControl made by Telerik and not the standard TextBox. That's why I couldn't see the TextAlign property - it's not there!

Comment: I think it's the `TextAlignment` property on the RadControls of Telerik. I'm not sure about it :)

Answer (score 3):

Use  the [Textalign](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.textalign.aspx) Property. It uses the [Horizontal Alignment Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.horizontalalignment.aspx) which wil give you Left, Right or Center Alignment.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the TextAlign property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.textalign